# Create object with new name each time form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to figure out how to collect the field values of a form which updates another section on the page to create an object each time it is submitted. I can create an object each time by using `.serializeArray()` but i want to be able to create an object with a new name each time it submits. I was thinking of using `each()` to create a new name with i=1 and i++ each time but not sure if this is even the correct way to go about getting the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [_.uniqueId](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org). Just set the object name to the result of the function and you'll always have a unique name.

```
  var idCounter = 0;
  var uniqueId = function(prefix) {
    var id = ++idCounter + '';
    return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
  };


var formvalues = {};
forvalues[uniqueId("data")] = {a:1,b:2};//or whatever ur form serializes to
console.log(formvalues); // {data1: {a:1,b:2}}
```

Comment: @Alan_N yes, see http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-130 and I updated my post

Comment: Thanks, I will have to check it out since I haven't used underscore before.

Comment: @Alan_N you don't need to use all of underscore; you can just use the single function if you dont have need for the rest of the library

Comment: I think i need to take a step back and work on creating object each time the form is submitted. Then I can look at different names. Thanks for the help.